# partial use of doctrine on an existing php project

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am a new developer on an existing php project that respect its proper mvc.
I have successfully "plug" a Symfony installation on it, in order to replace some of the already existing Symfony components such as Router, Request etc...

I have some functionalities to develop and I am isolating them under one bundle.

My question is : can I use Doctrine for this one in order to start a sanitize work on the existing database ? If I want to use foreign keys with the existing others tables I need to configure the mapping on them...It's a problem because I cannot start a refactoring for the objects of this project that are not entities-like. Is there a solution to use doctrine only for my bundle and keeping the use of foreign-keys, cascading etc... ?

Thank you for all

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to only generate the entities for your isolated bundle, you can do it.

Check documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html

Are you planning to create your tables in the same database or in a differente database?

Comment: Thank you bkazuo. I have already do the job of preparing my entities in my proper bundle. My problem is about the foreign keys with the objects of the existing project (unmapped by doctrine)...
I am on the same database